# SOAP implementation of UPnP architecture

Tags: xml, linux, curl, soap, upnp

I am trying to implement UPnP AV control point. i completed till description phase of the architecture. To get the contents of the server from browse action, I am using CURL command as below.

curl -o response.xml -H "Host: 192.168.1.47:2869" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; Charset="UTF-8"" -H "SOAPAction: "http://192.168.1.47:2869/upnphost/udhisapi.dll?content=uuid:67240e36-10e0-45f6-9c4b-e18cdd53360e"" -d @request.xml -X POST http://192.168.1.47:2869/upnphost/udhisapi.dll?control=uuid:99261858-3c45-41b5-87fd-3f30b4700005+urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ContentDirectory

The URL under SOAPAction is the service description url of the server.
The URL after POST is the control URL of the server.

My request.xml is as below:

```
   <?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:Envelope
        xmlns:s = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
        s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding">
        <s:Body>
           <u:Browse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:Service:ContentDirectory:1">
                   <ObjectID>"0"</ObjectID>
                   <BrowseFlag>"BrowseDirectChildren"</BrowseFlag>
                   <Filter>"*"</Filter>
                   <StartingIndex>0</StartingIndex>
                   <RequestedCount>3</RequestedCount>
                   <SortCriteria>""</SortCriteria>

           </u:Browse>
    </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

`

The response XML that I get does not contain the body content that i require. The response xml is:

```
    <s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
       <s:Fault>
           <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
           <faultstring>UPnPError</faultstring>
           <detail>
              <UPnPError>
                  <errorCode>401</errorCode>
                   <errorDescription>Invalid Action</errorDescription>
              </UPnPError>
           </detail>
    </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

How do I get the contents of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soapaction should be the fully specified identifier of the action you want to call. You are sending a URL to the service description instead. The following should work better:

```
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1#Browse"
```

Your xml may also be invalid, the angle brackets don't seem to match. I would also check the quoting of the Browse argument values: I believe none of them should be quoted.

Comment: i changed the soapaction. now my error is invalid args.

Comment: Look at the '<' and '>' that you use to enclose `s:envelope` and it's attributes. There seems to be an extra '>'.

Comment: Check the ContentDirectory specification: I'm guessing `BrowseFlag` value (in your case BrowseDirectChildren) should not be quoted because it's not a string but an enumeration.

Comment: @jku `BrowseFlag` is a string.  An enumeration in this case is just a string with an allowedValueList that defines a set of acceptable string inputs.

Comment: simonc is correct. I guess the reason it looked wrong to me is that none of the variable values should be quoted.

Comment: In my actual xml, I didn't have an extra ">". Browse flag is a string. But still I have argument error. So do u want me to remove "" for all arguments? Then how can I define it as a string?

Comment: The variable types are defined by the service description. Quotation marks should not be there (the service is almost certainly considering them parts of the strings now).